# Make x label horizontal in ChartJS

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, chart.js

[image]

Drawing a line chart with ChartJS 1.0.1 as above. As it shows, the label in the x-axis is not horizontal although there are enough space. How can I make it horizontal?

A side question, noticed the y label, there are 1-2px clipped. How to fix that?

Comment: the tricky thing here is, IMO, the label still needs to be clearly linked to one of the values, place it horizontal and it will span around 3 of them making it confusing which label it is really attached to. A quick fix for the cut off y is a quick rewrite of the template to add a leading space. scaleLabel: " <%= value%> "

Answer (score 46):

If you are using chart.js 2.x, just set **maxRotation: 0** and **minRotation: 0** in ticks options. If you want them vertical, set **maxRotation: 90** and **minRotation: 90** instead. And if you want to all x-labels, you may want to set **autoSkip: false**. The following is an example.

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: chartData,
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          autoSkip: false,
          maxRotation: 0,
          minRotation: 0
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

example of 0 degree
[image]

example of 90 degree 
[image]

Comment: Great  it's working only more data but chart data have only one data it will not apply min rotation. why ? any idea please suggest me

Comment: Is there any way to make the words wrap instead of overlapping them?

Comment: @jonjie I'm looking to find a way to make the words wrap as well. Any luck on that front?

Answer (score 2):

Use **Rotation** in `scales > x > ticks`

```js
scales: {
   x: {
    ticks: {
      autoSkip: false,
      maxRotation: 90,
      minRotation: 90
    }
   }
}
```

```js
let chart = new Chart('myChart', {

type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3]
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            x: {
                ticks: {
                  autoSkip: false,
                  maxRotation: 90,
                  minRotation: 90
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.6.2/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

try fix the function calculateXLabelRotation in chart.js

```
calculateXLabelRotation : function(){
    ...
        //↓↓↓
        this.xLabelRotation = 0;
        //↑↑↑
        if (this.xLabelRotation > 0){
            this.endPoint -= Math.sin(toRadians(this.xLabelRotation))*originalLabelWidth + 3;
        }
    ...
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my options config

```
const options = {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        position: 'top',
      },
      tooltip: {
        enabled: true
      },
    },
    scales: {
        xAxis: {
            ticks: {
                maxTicksLimit: 7,
                minRotation: 0,
                maxRotation: 0
            }
        }
    }
  };
```