# ChartJS horizontal label are 1-2px clipped

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, chart.js

I have same problem as mentioned on post: [Make x label horizontal in ChartJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28031873/make-x-label-horizontal-in-chartjs)

Note that for me interesting only question about y labels. How format or align "y" labels?

Comment: You might want to add how exactly you want to format and align the y labels - the other question simply asks for a horizontal layout. Is that enough for you? What is the alignment part you want?

Comment: Hi. As you see from screenshot, labels are not showns correctly. I want to find where to change settings for correctly display horizontal labels.

Comment: super quick fix, prefix the labels with a space

Comment: actually just realized i wrote the same comment on that question, did it not work?

Comment: @Quince Y labels added automatically. And i don't need change it with manually data.

Comment: Ill add an answer to show what i mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick fix for this can be to add a leading space to the Y-Labels. You can do this by editing the `scaleLabel` template to include the space

```
scaleLabel: " <%= value%>"
```

just pass this in as one of the options when creating the graph